# How to put text,buttons etc inside the picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put inside the image the code but I failed.What is the problem about that? I use microsoft word expression web 4.0. How to put text,buttons etc inside the picture?

```html
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  E-mail:<br />
  <input type="text" name="mail" /><img
    alt=""
    height="724"
    src="email-client-market-share-2019-blog.png"
    width="1380"
  /><br />
  Comment:<br />
  <input type="text" name="comment" size="50" /><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: Inside the picture?

Comment: yes that i mean @evolutionxbox

Comment: May you provide an example of what you want?

Comment: If you run that code you will see that everything is outside from the image.I want what it is outside to be in the image

Comment: I can't see any image. Remember, I don't have access to your computer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/xnhGN5J i want to go in the image . As you can see on that image it says  Send email ,Send e-mail to email@hotmail.com etc and it is out. I want to go in the pink image

Comment: You can use css. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: I don't want it as background..............

Comment: Why do you not?

Comment: I don't see an image in the code you are showing, but you should look into layers and floats.  Put a div tag holding the picture with the style set to the lowest layer (0) and then another div tag holding the form with the style set to either float or absolute position the xy coords.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index` in the CSS to do that. Put the image on `z-index: 1;` and the elements you want to place over it to `z-index: '>1';`.

Answer (score 0):

refer this code and see if it works for you, save this code as index.html and run on the browser to see the result !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Button on Image</h2>
<p>Add a button to an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!!